# Can you define a maybe property that is not nullable in Yesod Persist?

Tags: yesod, haskell-persistent

I am still quite new to Yesod so I might be missing something essential.

My understanding is that adding the `Maybe` attribute to a Persist Entity field seems to both make the attribute non nullable in the database as well as wrapping it in a Maybe in the Data definition. I tried creating a test Entity with a timestamp that has a `default=CURRENT_TIME`. If I now send a JSON representation of this entity without the timestamp, I get an error about the missing timestamp when I try to use `requireJsonBody`. I guess I could add `Maybe` to the timestamp to get the JSON parsing to succeed. But then I would not have the non null constraint for the column in the database anymore?

Comment: Which persistent backend are you using?